# Is unit testing always automated?

Tags: unit-testing

Can anyone provide an source that says that unit testing is not always done in an automated or programmatic way? I always assumed it meant testing code through code. I have a bet on this, so I need solid sources.

Comment: Like having people test your stuff in chain? Isn't that the principle of (private|public) beta-test? :)

Comment: You made a bad bet. Unit testing is a methodology, not an implementation.

Comment: You can change wikipedia and then show your friend.  Make sure to change it back, though. (this is a joke, please don't do this :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing):

[A unit test's] implementation can vary from being very manual (pencil and paper) to being formalized as part of build automation.

I don't think you will win your bet. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are going to lose the money / beer / doughnuts, unit testing can be automated thru various test frameworks (such as nunit) or purely be done manually.

Comment: it was actually a muffin and a coffee